Bridget Riley - Movement in Squares and Circles
Bridget Riley
Bridget Riley (born 1931 in London) is an English painter known for her op art paintings. Alongside Victor Vasarely and Vera Molnár, she is one of the best-known representatives of this art movement.

Bridget Riley at Gallery One, London, 1963
Riley studied art at Goldsmiths' College (1949–52), and later at the Royal College of Art (1952–55). During the early 1960s Riley began to paint the black and white works for which she first became known. They present a great variety of geometric forms that produce sensations of movement or colour. Riley began investigating colour in 1967, the year in which she produced her first stripe painting.

Bridget Riley, preparatory drawing, 1968
As seen above Riley meticulously plans her compositions with preparatory drawings and collage techniques. Her assistants then paint the final canvases with great precision under her instruction.
Bridget Riley's works are featured in major international museums, including MoMA, NewYork and Tate Modern, London.
Movement in Squares
This seminal painting from 1961 marks Riley’s first major breakthrough into abstraction. Using the simple form of the square, she achieved perceptual effects of motion and space that paved the way for her subsequent black-and-white paintings.

Bridget Riley, Movement in Squares (left) and my reproduction (right)
Despite the seemingly simple pattern I couldn't find an algorithmic solution and had to "manually" insert the rectangle coordinates:
squares[{c_, d_}] :=
 With[{r = Rectangle},
  {c, r[{0.0, i}, {1.0, i + 1}], d, r[{1.0, i}, {2.0, i + 1}],
   c, r[{2.0, i}, {2.9, i + 1}], d, r[{2.9, i}, {3.8, i + 1}],
   c, r[{3.8, i}, {4.6, i + 1}], d, r[{4.6, i}, {5.4, i + 1}],
   c, r[{5.4, i}, {6.1, i + 1}], d, r[{6.1, i}, {6.8, i + 1}],
   c, r[{6.8, i}, {7.4, i + 1}], d, r[{7.4, i}, {8.0, i + 1}],
   c, r[{8.0, i}, {8.5, i + 1}], d, r[{8.5, i}, {9.0, i + 1}],
   c, r[{9.0, i}, {9.4, i + 1}], d, r[{9.4, i}, {9.8, i + 1}],
   c, r[{9.8, i}, {10.1, i + 1}], d, r[{10.1, i}, {10.4, i + 1}],
   c, r[{10.4, i}, {10.6, i + 1}], d, r[{10.6, i}, {10.8, i + 1}],
   c, r[{10.8, i}, {10.9, i + 1}], d, r[{10.9, i}, {11.0, i + 1}],
   c, r[{11.0, i}, {11.1, i + 1}], d, r[{11.1, i}, {11.2, i + 1}],
   c, r[{11.2, i}, {11.3, i + 1}], d, r[{11.3, i}, {11.5, i + 1}],
   c, r[{11.5, i}, {11.8, i + 1}], d, r[{11.8, i}, {12.1, i + 1}],
   c, r[{12.1, i}, {12.5, i + 1}], d, r[{12.5, i}, {12.9, i + 1}],
   c, r[{12.9, i}, {13.4, i + 1}], d, r[{13.4, i}, {13.9, i + 1}],
   c, r[{13.9, i}, {14.5, i + 1}], d, r[{14.5, i}, {15.1, i + 1}],
   c, r[{15.1, i}, {15.8, i + 1}], d, r[{15.8, i}, {16.5, i + 1}]}]

bw = squares[{Black, GrayLevel[1]}];
wb = squares[{GrayLevel[1], Black}];

Graphics[Table[{bw, wb}[[Mod[i, 2] + 1]], {i, 1, 15}], AspectRatio -> 1]


Result like shown above

Movement in Circles

Bridget Riley, Pause, 1964
Question
I want to find an elegant, algorithmic way to reproduce "Movement in Squares". Since my ultimate goal is to replicate "Pause" (shown above), I would be particularly grateful for solutions that also address the latter.

I like your posts very much and I think the art-math connection is an excellent way to demonstrate the MA capabilities. They would be even better if follow some logical rules on what constitute a solution. For instance, the accepted answer (1st part) does not even answer your question(s). And the 2nd part (to my humble opinion) is not better than numerous other answers. I think, these enthusiastic people working hard on solving your problems deserve at least an explanation on what motivated your choice of winner. This is certainly not the time order, nor the completeness or generality order.

Thanks for your feedback, yarchik. I agree that other answers (all of them are great and  deserve acceptance) more closely stick to the question. My explanation: I was somehow overwhelmed by the pure beauty of azerbajdjan's first answer (the colour waves). I had worked for hours without too much success on these sinusoids (see my comment under his answer), and didn't even dare to pose it as a question because it seemed so complicated. In the future I will try to better match question and acceptance. Promised. And last but not least: Thanks to everybody for the beautiful answers.

For the first picture, it seems like the  propagation of the wave, maybe we can consider  the wave equation to get the general drawing method, but upto now it still difficult for me, so I concentrate at the last picture :)

Since I like the color image more than the black-and-white...
c1 := RGBColor[({0, 155, 175} + RandomInteger[{-20, 20}, 3])/255]
c2 := RGBColor[({238, 60, 46} + RandomInteger[{-20, 20}, 3])/255]
color := {c1, c2, None, c2, c1, None}
fil = MapIndexed[#[[1]] -> {{#[[2]]}, color[[Mod[First@#2, 6, 1]]]} &,
    Partition[Range[51], 2, 1]];
style = Flatten[
   Append[#, #[[2]]] & /@ 
    Partition[DeleteCases[fil[[All, 2, 2]], None], 2]];

Plot[Evaluate@
  Join[Table[
    1/5 (1 + n - Cos[(n Pi)/5 + (2 Pi x)/3]), {n, 14, -3, -1}], 
   Table[1/5 (-5 - n - Cos[(n Pi)/5 + (2 Pi x)/3]), {n, -2, 30}]], {x,
   0, 10}, Filling -> fil, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 GridLines -> {Range[-2, 12, 0.1], Range[-8, 4, 0.1]}, 
 PlotStyle -> style, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 10.21}, {-7.41, 3.4}}, ImagePadding -> 0.1, 
 Background -> RGBColor[{240, 239, 221}/255]]



"1:eJytU11v0zAU3Qu/gD9QNGlq1evWdpKt+2i1rqzTEENVy5vrBy8xJcKzoySDjCj/\
HdupYIixVYIX+9q+9/j43OM3t2a5ev1qby8mJ+\
Pl1cXMKJOzbo2BRBGQo6jpL4VOzN21LuVG5qxGFAPFDQS8N6RRxNeY0Jj+\
VkyDERxiCA93K3ZVJ+M6JhBT+\
GC0dLNdubBxGZ9SNb4R2bVOZCUTts8Y4RxN6tpGlPMGPARjNyZh8zQvyvN9Codgk3hzAAu\
Rl2mZGs0smY1kEeFA3eGpwy7KByXHcyXKUmo2zTKp7Q3QIvOD4fmv8rdSyVLORCELZikxN\
lXKItk8T5W76HR9Mg+mgUPOyHihTMkuvwp1L0p5/\
s6kmn0Ut0oyMow6XdLXaGYK1tWdRdobRv0utUGn6g2tPFBrICGgABBpODwqQxF6oQ5RCHB\
jadUV2EYGg+MG5qlSqd6giWUO0yKTcbkU9lloMr0vzZ0NY7jK0+\
R9qmVhtW21skgkHBDAAyvadmsEoV834J63cvqhiZcRppWrnQtVSH/\
oK1yjEB60SA3U6GgQQjAImwau78RGLkSSeGYWFC5E/\
GWTm3udoMlPR9U0tLYJjoFS0njf8FbmjP5d4pnRie+bUJdVlsuicD3cQXhksY9mxI/\
HfhzNcxE7qAtTsXY/\
WK872ocYOu0Wwe2at9NZdYb5k118htkLvf3f1B4bBREM9mfubg2bv5s3rnLx8Iw12nu9Lc\
g/+2L7/1afzTeWUcjIH5f1R8Mtc/LUrav0u80kAcb8B4Kgj/U=" // 
  Uncompress // ToExpression



im = Rasterize[
   Image[Table[Mod[i + j, 2], {i, 20}, {j, 20}], ImageSize -> 400], 
   RasterSize -> 800];
ImageTransformation[im, {Sqrt[Abs[2 #[[1]] - 1]], #[[2]]} &]




I tried this without success for approx. 3 hours - it's very difficult to find your formula.

@eldo Yes, it needed quite some time.

I suggest to use Texture together with Plot3D. This results in a rather short code and allows for many generalisations.
texture = 
 Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], 
 Disk[{-1, -1}, 0.5], Disk[{1, 1}, 0.5], 
 Disk[{-1, 1}, 0.5], Disk[{1, -1}, 0.5]}, 
 PlotRange -> 1, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]

g1=Plot3D[LogisticSigmoid[(-x + 2)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1 - 5 #3, #2} &), 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Texture[texture]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]


and the result 
Here is another visualisation:
Plot3D[ArcTan[x] ArcTan[y], {x, -7.5, 7.5}, {y, -7.5, 7.5}, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1 (1 - 0.2 #3), #2 (1 - 0.2 #3)} &), 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Texture[texture]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]


It seems, the artist added shading as additional level. This can also be accomplished with my method:
g2 = Plot3D[
  ArcTan[x + y] ArcTan[y - x] Sin[x + y] + 5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0.5]}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[z]]];
Show[{g1, g2}, PlotRange -> All]




We use the Bump function

Clear["Global`*"];
centers = 
  Select[Tuples[{Range[-20, 20, 1], Range[-20, 20, 1]}], 
   Mod[Last@# - First@#, 2] == 0 &];
disks = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ (Disk[#, 1/2] & /@ centers) // 
   RegionUnion;
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[-(1/x)], x > 0}}];
g[x_] := f[x]/(f[x] + f[1 - x]);
bump[a_, b_, c_, d_][x_] := g[(x - a)/(b - a)]  g[(d - x)/(d - c)];
factor = .15;
kernel[R_, r_][x_] := -(1 - factor)  bump[-R, -r, r, R][x];
plot1 = Plot[kernel[10, .01][x], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == kernel[10, .01][x], y[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, -30, 30}];
plot2 = Plot[sol[x], {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}]


draw[reg_] := Module[{tran, graph},
  tran[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := {x, y} + 
    sol[RegionDistance[reg, {x, y}]]*
     Normalize@({x, y} - RegionNearest[reg, {x, y}]);
  graph = 
   RegionPlot[disks, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
    Frame -> False, 
    DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real} :> tran@{x, y}], 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    MaxRecursion -> 0];
  Show[graph, PlotRange -> 15, ImageSize -> Large]]

regs = {InfiniteLine[{8, 0}, {0, 1}], HalfSpace[{2, 1}, {0, 0}], 
   Disk[{0, 0}, 8], Circle[{0, 0}, 8]};
GraphicsGrid[Partition[draw /@ regs, 2, 2]]



test another region and another transformation.

Clear[disks, reg, dist, tran, g2]; 
disks = 
 RegionDifference[
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
   Rectangle[{-15 - 1/2, -15 - 1/2}, {15 + 1/2, 15 + 1/2}], 
  RegionUnion[
   Flatten@Table[
     BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Disk[{i, j}, 1/2], {i, -15, 
      15}, {j, -15, 15}]]];
reg = Circle[{0, 0}, 8];
dist = 4;
tran[{x_, y_}] := 
  If[RegionDistance[reg, {x, y}] <= 
    dist, {x, 
     y} - .8 (1 - RegionDistance[reg, {x, y}]/dist)^2 ({x, y} - 
       RegionNearest[reg, {x, y}]), {x, y}];
g2 = RegionPlot[disks, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> False, 
   DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real} :> tran@{x, y}], 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0];
Show[g2, PlotRange -> 12, ImageSize -> Large]



Starting from a similar idea like the one proposed in the question:
seq = Join[
    Flatten[Table[{i, i}, {i, Subdivide[1, 0.1, 10]}]]
  , Flatten[Table[{i, i}, {i, Subdivide[0.1, 0.7, 5]}]]];

acc = seq // Accumulate //  Prepend[0]@# &;

rectangles[y_] := Table[
  {If[Or[And[Mod[x, 2] == 1, Mod[y, 2] == 1]
       , And[Mod[x, 2] == 0, Mod[y, 2] == 0 ]]
     , Black, Directive[Opacity[0], White]]
   , Rectangle[{acc[[x]], y}, {acc[[x + 1]], y + 1}]}
, {x, 1, Length[acc] - 1}]

disks[y_] := Table[
  {If[Or[And[Mod[x, 2] == 1, Mod[y, 2] == 1]
     , And[Mod[x, 2] == 0, Mod[y, 2] == 0 ]]
    , Black, Directive[Opacity[0], White]]
   , Scale[
      Translate[
       Disk[{acc[[x]], y}], {acc[[x + 1]], y + 1}], {acc[[x + 1]] - acc[[x]], 1}]}
, {x, 1, Length[acc] - 1}]

Table[rectangles[n], {n, 1, 12}] // Graphics

Table[disks[n], {n, 1, 12}] // Graphics



An attempt to replicate Pause
seq = Join[
  Flatten[Table[{i, i}, {i, Subdivide[1, 0.1, 12]}]]
, Flatten[Table[{i, i}, {i, Subdivide[0.1, 1, 6]}]]];

acc = seq // Accumulate // Prepend[0]@# &;

disks[y_,  opt_] := 
 Table[{If[Or[And[Mod[x, 2] == 1, Mod[y, 2] == 1, FreeQ[Keys@opt, x]]
     , And[Mod[x, 2] == 0, Mod[y, 2] == 0, FreeQ[Keys@opt, x]]]
     , Black, Directive[Opacity[0], White]]
   , Scale[Translate[
      Disk[{acc[[x]], y}], {acc[[x + 1]], y + 1}], {acc[[x + 1]] - acc[[x]], 1}]}
  , {x, 1, Length[acc] - 1}]

shadows[y_, opt_] := 
 Table[{If[! FreeQ[Keys@opt, x], opt[x], Directive[Opacity[0], White]] 
   , Scale[Translate[
      Disk[{acc[[x]], y}], {acc[[x + 1]], y + 1}], {acc[[x + 1]] - acc[[x]], 1}]}
  , {x, 1, Length[acc] - 1}]

colors = <|
     2 -> GrayLevel[.8], 4 -> GrayLevel[.8],  6 -> GrayLevel[.7]
   , 8 -> GrayLevel[.7], 10 -> GrayLevel[.5], 12 -> GrayLevel[.4]
   , 30 -> GrayLevel[.4], 32 -> GrayLevel[.5], 34 -> GrayLevel[.6]
   , 36 -> GrayLevel[.7], 38 -> GrayLevel[.85], 40 -> GrayLevel[.8]
   , 42 -> GrayLevel[.7], 44 -> GrayLevel[.6], 46 -> GrayLevel[.4]|>;

Table[colors = KeyMap[# - 1 &, colors]; 
  {disks[n, colors], shadows[n, colors]}, {n, 1, 22}] //
 Graphics[#, ImageSize -> Medium, Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8]] &



We may start with a regular grid of squares:
n=30; 
squares = 
      Flatten[Table[
        Rectangle[{i, If[EvenQ[i], j, j + 1]}, {i + 1, 
          1 + If[EvenQ[i], j, j + 1]}], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n, 2}], 1];


Then, we can distort the grid along the x axis according to a function. To get the wanted distortion, this function should have a slope of approximately 1 at the beginning and end and have a smaller slope somewhere in the middle. We may define such a function using "Manipulate" and "BezierFunction":
n=30;    
Manipulate[
     (bez = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, pts[[1]], pts[[2]], pts[[3]], 
         pts[[4]], {n, n}}];
      ParametricPlot[ bez[x], {x, 0, 1}(*,PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}}*)])
     , {{pts, {{n/4, n/2}, {n /8, n/2}, {n  3/4, n/2}, {n  7/8, 
         n/2}}}, {0, 0}, {n, n}, Locator}, TrackedSymbols :> {pts}]


Finally we define a function to transform the grid and draw the distorted grid:
distort[{x_?NumericQ, y_}] := {bez[x/(1 + n)][[2]], y};
squares = 
  Flatten[Table[
    Rectangle[{i, If[EvenQ[i], j, j + 1]}, {i + 1, 
      1 + If[EvenQ[i], j, j + 1]}], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n, 2}], 1];
squares = squares /. {x_, y_} :> distort[{x, y}];
Graphics[squares]


Now, you may play with different distortion functions, have fun.

Good idea to use BezierFunction but the function you create in the manipulate does not correspond to the transformation function bez[x/(1 + n)][[2]], this function is completely different from what is depicted in the manipulate. Simply said parametric function {x, bez[x][[2]]} used for transformation is not same as bez[x] depicted in manipulate.
